# Windows JVM is limiting upload speed of http output stream

Tags: java, windows, jvm, outputstream

I have desktop java application for uploading files to some server and I do it with simple output stream

```
socket.getOutputStream();
outputStream.write(buffer, 0, bytesRead);
```

on osx or linux its working properly, but on windows is maximum speed at around 1MB/s but on osx on same line is it over 4MB/s.

im using java 6, but on java 7 or on unofficil windows openjdk is it same

do you have any idea what can i do with this problem?

Comment: Do you know the trouble is in the java layer? Can you do an ftp put or similar to compare bulk TCP send performance? Doesn't windows have some network throttling built in?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its impossible to tell without knowing any details, but I would start playing with the parameters:

- Try enlarging the buffer variable
- Enlarge the sockets's send buffer: setSendBufferSize()
- Play with the TCP options: setTcpNoDelay(true/false) etc.
- Ensure that the problem is the socket and not I/O by removing the reading and just writing the buffer N times to generate enough data. It may be the source device that is so slow and not the socket.